# Use the Ubuntu Server Installer to overwrite an existing Ubuntu system

Tags: ubuntu, 64-bit

I want to reinstall Ubuntu to have a 64 bit OS, from my old 32 bit. In the Ubuntu installer, it will not show my existing install to overwrite, just the flash drive that I am using to install it. How could I do this?

Under `use guided partition with LVM`, it shows:

```
SCSI5 )0,0,0) (sda) - 2.1 GB Lexar JD Lightning
```

I need it to show my HDD. I have an existing install on there, but I need to upgrade it to a 64 bit install. I could care less to what happens with the files on there currently.

Comment: What flash drive? How are you running the installer?

Comment: @terdon I'm using a 2GB flash drive with the 12.10 installer on the drive.

Comment: So you have created a bootable flash drive and are booting from it? If so, please [edit] your question to include that information. Also perhaps a screenshot showing your problem?

Comment: terdon, that's correct. While my phone's not on me (to take the photo), I'll put the text in the question

Comment: Once you boot into the live session from your USB drive, you can take a screenshot by hittink the `prnt screen` button or by running `gnome-screenshot` from a terminal.

Comment: terdon, It's Ubuntu Server, and it's not a live drive.

Comment: Updated the post